# Logback.xml is printing only INFO level logs

Tags: java, logback

Here is my application.

```
package com.spectrum.sci.dsb;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.spectrum.sci.dsb")
public class DsbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DsbApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is part of my service class.

```
public ResponseEntity<String> getUCANService(UCANRequest ucanRequest) {
        log.info("Entering getUCANService..." + ucanRequest.toString() );
        
        String ucanId = ucanRequest.getUcanId();
        String namespace = ucanRequest.getNamespace();
        
     
        String uCanXmlString = applicationPropertyReader.readUCanRequestFile();
        ASBMessage asbMessage = DSBUtil.convertXmlStringToASBMessageObj(uCanXmlString);
        log.debug("ASBMessage = " + asbMessage.getBody().getAccount().getId().getValue());
           
        String ucanRequestStr = replaceXmlStringWithUcanOrigData(ucanId, namespace, uCanXmlString);
        
        return dsbClient.getDSBClient(ucanRequestStr);
    }
```

Here is my `logback.xml`

```xml
<configuration debug="true">

    <logger name="com.spectrum.sci.dsb" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="httpclient" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.context" level="WARN" />
     <logger name="org.springframework.core" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.beans" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="DEBUG" />
    
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logs/dsb.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/dsb.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%level] [Context:%logger{0}] [%X] [%msg]%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
    
</configuration>
```

I have correct package `com.spectrum.sci.dsb` both in my application and `logback.xml`.

But, it is printing `INFO` level logs. If I set VM args using RUN Configuration to `DEBUG` it prints the `DEBUG` level message but I don't want to set in VM args. I would like to put in `logback.xml` so that prod/dev can be interchangable.

Comment: Sounds like using `<root level="DEBUG">` should do the trick. Am I missing something?

Comment: I did root level as DEBUG and it works. But, I guess root level is for root transactions, not my package level. Would like configure in package level only